# What is the best email frequency for high volume transactional emailing?

Tags: email, hotmail

Let's say we send about 100k emails per day to our users.
These are all transactional emails ("You received a new message",etc.)

In order to reduce the number of emails we group those transactions into summary emails and send those summary emails every 6 hours or so.
So every 6 hours or so we send about 25k emails.

From particularly hotmail's perspective is it a bad practice to send all these emails every six hours.

Would it be better to send these emails every hour for instance?

Thanks,
Haluk

Comment: Way off-topic here.  I don't know whether this should go to Server Fault, Webmasters, or even if there's no appropriate site.  This may also be worth taking this up with sites and organizations that don't like what you're doing.  So Hotmail doesn't want you to send emails like that:  are you sending from Hotmail or are many of your users on it?  If they don't like the periodic emails, what do they want/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The best way to send - is to send uniformly. Every hour is better then every 6 hours. Every minute is better. Think how mail services like gmail work. They send and receive mail every minute. If you'll send a large chank of mail at a short time and then will do a delay - that will look more like spam.

Comment: Thank you Dmitriy. I was thinking similarly too.